# Bone is parenting to wrong vertices

Tags: rigging, armature

My problem is that when I parent my arm object to the arm armature, the middle bone attaches itself to the beginning of the arm, because of that whole thing bends wrong and I don't seem to know what the problem might be 
Here is a look at the arm model with armature:
[image]

And here is the same model but bent:
[image]

For additional context, this arm is a mirror copy of another arm, but the other one does not seem to have this issue

Also here is the blend file: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join the armatures together and also join the objects together. Also you need to recalculate the normals as you have some inverted normals (select all the vertices in *Edit* mode and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: The old Inverted normals problem!  I was about to suggest he submit this as a bug when I saw your posting.